# Net beans debugger on mac not working

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, mamp, xdebug

my net beans debugger on my mac is not working and I am not sure why.
This is the php.ini file on my MAMP. Its located in my php5.6.2. folder.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=8080
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

My local host is running on port 8080 so here are the changes I made in the netbeans preference.

[image]
I am not sure if the next picture should have that path name or should I change it to the path name of the file that my project folder is located in ??
[image]

So other than this when I run the debugger it shows

```
http://localhost/pocketAllowence/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
```

It doesnt show localhost:8080 and then the rest. So not sure what to do to fix it.